# Why doesn't this congruence have solutions $x^2=83 \pmod{83^{2000}}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Why doesn't this congruence have solutions $x^2=83 \pmod{83^{2000}}$

I know $x^2=83 \pmod{83}$ has a solution, I'm not sure how to show the above congruence doesn't though.

Comment: Because $83$ is a prime factor that appears in the answer an **odd** number of times ($2001$ to be accurate). And in a perfect square, each prime factor must appear an **even** number of times.

Comment: If a prime divides a square $x^2$ then it divides $x$.

Comment: BTW, "$83\pmod{83}$" is a senseless notation. In order for "$k\pmod{83}$" to make sense, $k$ has to be an integer between $0$ and $79$.

Comment: @barakmanos the notation is fine. 83 mod 83 is just 0 mod 83

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \color{green}{x^2} = p + p^2n = \color{#c00}p(1+pn)$ has $\color{green}{\,\rm evenly}\,$ many $p$'s on the left, but $\color{#c00}{\rm\,oddly}\,$ many on the right (since $\,p\nmid 1+pn),\,$ when their (unique!) prime factorizations are considered, for $\,p\,$ prime.